# Azure DevOps Server: WIQL work item from backlog

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-server-2019, wiql

How to select/filter workitems from backlog and their childs?

I tried to filter by "Backlog Priority" field and set it greater than 0, but not sure that it's correct way to do that. Couldn't find any usefull information on the internet.

Comment: What do you want to find? Backlog Items  (on the top level) and their childs?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to find/filter backlog items (I mean not type of workitem, but workitems in backlog section) no matter which iteration/sprint set or even doesn't set at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a query to find the workitems in backlog, you can create a query with one click on the backlog. The query result contains all the workitems and their childs in the backlog. Then you can sort the query results.

[image]

[image]

Update:

Then you can install this extension [Wiql Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor) and check/edit the  query wiql. It will contain `where clause` you need. You can also edit it to meet your needs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Miao for your suggestion, but I need to filter workitems in queries (by some field/parameters/value) in order to use that filter (where clause) in another system

Comment: Hi @OleksiiDz, there is currently no default field used to define whether a workitem is on the backlog. You can [add a custom field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-field?view=azure-devops) if you need. In addition, I updated the answer to added how to edit query wiql.